# How do I combine a function representing an x value with a function representing a y value?

Tags: plotting

I have two functions, one that generates my x values and one that generates my y values, and I want to merge the data to get a single line plot. This is easily done in excel, but I can't figure out how to do it in mathematica. I did it in excel and it should look like this:[image: excel plot]. I have written a code that looks like this, where my x and y values are functions of theta

```
x = 1/72 Cos[θ] (2 + 2 Cos[θ] + 27 Sin[θ])

y = 1/72 Sin[θ] (2 + 2 Cos[θ] + 27 Sin[θ])
```

I'm pretty sure my issue is just not knowing which plotting function to use, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{
   1/72 Cos[\[Theta]] (2 + 2 Cos[\[Theta]] + 27 Sin[\[Theta]]), 
   1/72 Sin[\[Theta]] (2 + 2 Cos[\[Theta]] + 27 Sin[\[Theta]])},
 {\[Theta], 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: u da man, vickto k

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

`ParametricPlot`as pointed out by Victor K is the most straightforward approach. You could also `Solve` for `y` as a function of `x`.

```
sol[x_] = y /. Solve[{
     x == 1/72 Cos[θ] (2 + 2 Cos[θ] + 27 Sin[θ]),
     y == 1/72 Sin[θ] (2 + 2 Cos[θ] + 27 Sin[θ])}, 
    y, {θ}, Reals];
```

There are four branches to the solution

```
Length@sol[x]

(* 4 *)

Plot[Evaluate@sol[x], {x, -0.25, 0.25},
 PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 0.25}, {-0.02, 0.42}},
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 AspectRatio -> 4/5,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The corresponding `ParametricPlot`(the range of `θ` is extended to `2 Pi`) is

```
ParametricPlot[{
  1/72 Cos[θ] (2 + 2 Cos[θ] + 27 Sin[θ]),
  1/72 Sin[θ] (2 + 2 Cos[θ] + 27 Sin[θ])},
 {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 0.25}, {-0.02, 0.42}}]
```

[image]